# Want to fetch mysql Field record in highchart tooltip

Tags: javascript, json, codeigniter, highcharts

Here I am using highchart with codeigniter. I got highchart record with graph but I want record comes from mysql database field of "zreadactivity" in tooltip. I could not get proper name in tooltip for "zreadactivity" as it contains record. So, I just want to know that where I am stuck?
Here is my code:
Controller:

```
public function branchwiseactivityavg()
    {
        $data = $this->Data->branch_wise_activities();

        $category = array();
        $category['name'] = 'EndDate'; 

        $series1 = array();
        $series1['name'] = 'TotalValue';

        $series2 = array();
        $series2['name'] = 'zreadactivity';

        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            $category['data'][] = $row->EndDate;
            $series1['data'][] = $row->TotalValue;
            $series2['data'][] = $row->zreadactivity;
        }
        $result = array();
        array_push($result,$category);
        array_push($result,$series1);
        array_push($result,$series2);


        print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    }
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() { 
            var options = { 
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container5',
                    type: 'column',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25,
                        zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Branch wise activities Last 30 Days',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: '',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories : []
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'TotalValue'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },    

                    tooltip: 
                        {
                             formatter: function() { return ' ' +
                                'EndDate: ' + this.x + '<br />' +
                                'TotalValue: ' + this.y + '<br />' +
                                'zreadactivity: ' + this.series.name;
                             }
                        },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },


                series: []

            };

            $.getJSON("branchwiseactivityavg", function(json) { 
            options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });

            });
                </script>
```

zreadactivity table:

```
zreadacivity
---------------
Refund
Exchange
Voids
Cancel
Discount
Price Overwrite
```

Answer (score 0):

  One way is to create JSON where for series' data each point is defined as an array like:

```
[value_from_TotalValue, value_from_zreadactivity]
```

and set [keys](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.keys) for series like:

```
series: [{keys: ['y','zreadactivity']}]
```

and in tooltip's formatter use `this.point.zreadactivity` to access zreadactivity.

  Other option is to build this structure for series in JavaScript after getting JSON data.

Example with keys: http://jsfiddle.net/yhx2dp2g/

Example without keys: http://jsfiddle.net/yhx2dp2g/1/